# How do I integrate Google Analytics if my project is linked to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm developing an android app for, for which I want integrate Firebase Analytics.
But apparently logging custom events and viewing those custom events in a dashboard is not easy.

And the Google App Engine project is linked to Firebase now, but I want to integrate Google Analytics for the same project in my android app.

But while trying to set up Google Analytics, when I try to select project and click on `CONTINUE TO Choose and configure services` I'm getting redirected to Firebase Analytics page.

Please help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firebase, you already have Firebase Analytics on your app (out of the box). If you check your Firebase Console, you'll notice that some events have already been collected.

And logging Custom Events is not really hard. You can check how to do it on the [Firebase Analytics Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events).

Comment: But I will prefer Google Analaytics instead of Firebase, so can you guide how to do it?

Comment: Try this link: https://medium.com/@lolevsky/integrating-firebase-analytics-with-google-analytics-b888ef243e83#.qcsv32g0b and this one: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6392697?hl=en